# php insert multi data by number

Tags: php

need insert multi data but user insert number in for loop
for example :

```
"items":[{"type":"type1","number":3}, 
         {"type":"type2","number":4}]
```

show:

```
type1
-type2
-type2
-type2
-type2

type1
-type2
-type2
-type2
-type2

type1
-type2
-type2
-type2
-type2
```

my code :

```
foreach($request->items as $k => $item) {
                    for ($i=0; $i < $request->items[$k]['number']; $i++) {
                        $details = new Property();
                        $details->title  = $request->items[$k]['type'];
                        $details->type = $request->items[$k]['type'];
                        $details->save();
                    }
            }
```

but not work well show only first loop and i need add more array

Comment: Undefined offset: 2

when use
for ($k=0; $k < $request->items[$k]['num']; $k++) {

Comment: Ye sry about that, my first comment was useless. Your inner loop uses the same details everytime. For `$i = 0`, `$i = 1`, `$i = 2` ... you use `$request->items[$k]['type'];` shouldn't you somehow use the `$i` variable?

Comment: Why do you have two loops? Looks like you only have one level of data.

Comment: i use $i for new loop

Comment: ArSeN how can u one loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You give one try this code:

```
    $items = ['{"type":"type1","number":3}', 
         '{"type":"type2","number":4}',
         '{"type":"type3","number":4}',
         '{"type":"type4","number":3}'];
// $items2 = json_decode($items[0]);
loop($items[0], $items, 0);

function loop($items, $x, $e) {
    $item = json_decode($items);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $item->number; $i++) {
        echo $item->type.'<br />';
        if (isset($x[$e+1])) {
            loop($x[$e+1], $x, $e+1);
        }
    }
}
```

you only need refactor.

Comment: I have tested with a json, so that would be $item[0]->number, I think.

Comment: in index i've number for loop as input ... user write count types